# HTTP Redirects with GET parameters

Tags: javascript, python, json, http, http-redirect

I have a case where I'm performing a redirect on a page but I'm also passing through some information in the GET that preferably should not be seen since it could identify a user or disclose information about them in the URL therefore could be history or picked up in an insecure network etc... The user is already logged in and validated at this point.

> https://example.com/page?message=Some+user+informaton&subuser=24

To prevent this I had two ideas:

- Access reference map - temporarily store the information I want to display in the users session with a cryptographically unique key that is used in the redirect then destroyed when the request has been completed. Still uses redirect logic e.g.

> https://example.com/page?redirectdata=xAe4Fdh4

- JavaScript + JSON - Submit the form to the server, server returns a JSON response of the url to redirect to and any extra parameres such as messages. Then use the JS to do a POST the server to not expose anything.

Which of these is the best way to implement a secure redirect?

Many thanks

Comment: Use POST, whether via javascript/ajax or html/form submit.  If you use html/form technique, you can save a step by not sending a url back to the user which he then loads, but rather serve up that page as the form response.

Comment: Is this redirect headed to the same domain or another domain? Are origin and destination under your control?

Comment: @Joseph Its to the same domain, so both are in my control